# How to check if a subquery has exactly one distinct result and a specified value concisely?

Tags: postgresql, duplication

I found myself writing the following:

```
select 'yes' 
where exists(select * from foo where val=1)
and not exists(select * from foo where val<>1);
```

and wondering if there is a more concise way without sacrificing too much readability.

I found one way which I am posting as an answer but I'm not entirely happy with it and would be very interested in alternatives

In this case `val` is unique within `foo` - there are no duplicates

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want exactly *one* row in the result of the subquery?

Comment: Which subquery?

Comment: The one you mention in the title. I wasn't sure whether it should be one result after or before "distinct".

Comment: Ah yes, that one :) I was rather confusingly referring to the sub-query in my *answer* - yours is far more specific and flexible, eg you can also use `count(distinct val)`, though in my real-world case it makes no difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concise, fast (especially with many rows), my favorite concerning *readability* and would work with dupes, too:

```
SELECT count(*) = 1 AND min(val) = 1 FROM foo;
```

Returns `TRUE` / `FALSE` .. or `NULL` - *only* in the case of exactly one row with `val IS NULL`, because `count()` never returns `NULL` or no row.

The second `1` in the example just happens to be the same as the first, because of your example.

---

The query in the question fails with `NULL` values. Consider the simple demo:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int, val int);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 1),(2, NULL);

SELECT 'yes' 
WHERE      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE val =  1)
AND    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE val <> 1);
```

[`IS DISTINCT FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html) would fix this, but it could still fail with duplicates in `val` - which you have ruled out for this case.

---

Your answer works fine.
Returns `'yes'` / no row.

I would prefer this shorter form, though. Don't forget that PostgreSQL (unlike Oracle) has a proper [`boolean` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html).

```
SELECT array_agg(val) = array[1] FROM foo;
```

Returns `TRUE` / `FALSE` / `NULL`.

Comment: excellent, thanks, I knew there would be a better way :)

Answer (score 5):

A variation on @Erwin's answer. No `COUNT()` at all, only `MIN()` and `MAX()`. It may be slightly more efficient with big table and (not in your case) duplicate `val`:

```
SELECT MIN(val) = 1 AND MAX(val) = 1 FROM foo;
```

Comment: +1 thanks. It handles nulls and duplicates differently of course (if there were any)

Comment: @Jack: Yes. Does your table have nulls? Or you want answers for both cases (with and without)?

Comment: no mine doesn't - I can use either :)

Comment: Would be *much* faster on bigger tables with a matching index, but performs identically in the absence of such an index - like when testing query results.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 'yes' where (select array_agg(val) from foo)=array[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This one returns `true`, `false` or an empty result:

```
 select j.val is null 
 from foo left join foo as j on j.val <> foo.val 
 where foo.val = 1 limit 1;
```

Comment: at first glance, this doesn't seem to return `false` if there are values in `foo` where `val<>1`?

Comment: @JackDouglas Oh, sorry. I understood the task wrong the first time. Fixed.

Comment: Works - except with `NULL` as value which has not been ruled out in this case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `NULL` can be worked out by using `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` I think.

Comment: @grayhemp: Not in this case. `LEFT JOIN foo j ON j.val <> foo.val` fails to detect a row with `j.val IS NULL` to begin with. If you'd include it with
`ON j.val IS DISTINCT FROM foo.val` you'd then need to check on another column of `j` defined `NOT NULL` to tell the two cases apart. But no additional column is defined.